# How to keep client passwords safe on server machine

Tags: windows, security, remote-access, administration

Is there any way to keep client third party service password secured from others being able to access server machine? 
Password is used to send messages between two system, from A->B. There are 3 actors:

1. client - owner of the infrastructure and user of system A and B
2. provider A - author of system A which have ablitity to RDP into client server and administrate it to keep system A working
3. service B - service providing access to system B, secured with password known to client which provider A shouldn't directly know

Every solution based on encryption and storing password in configuration/database is not an option because provider A will always have access to decrypting algorithm and mangled password.
Best solution right know is based on keeping password in server Windows Credential Manager. Provider A can use it inside message sender process by its code but password itself is not directly visible in server. It always can be retrived by provider A but it is a bit safer.

Comment: It's unclear why storing credentials in one place is fine while storing them in another place were not an option.

Comment: Because credential manager allow storing password outside of provider A system. I know it can still be fetched but it is a little harder then examine database row or config file which are daily basic administrative tasks. I'm afraid that there is no bullet proff solution.

Comment: Sounds like you don't understand encryption or security. Or both.

Comment: I'm afraid that I understand. From my perspective there is no acceptable solution for client problem. But maybe here I'm wrong so I'm asking for ideas.

Comment: *"\[...\] is not an option because provider A will always have access to decrypting algorithm"* - That strongly suggests, that you are failing to understand very basic concepts of (public key) cryptography. Having access to the decryption algorithm and encrypted data by itself does not provide any opportunity to uncover secrets.

Comment: My bad that I used encryption keyword. There is no any private-public key relation between provider A and service B. Provider A process still has to use plain form of password to access service B. In fact its basic auth http password. Changing B side is impossible. So encrypting password to store it somewhere where provider A is owner of both public and private key does not change anything.